# The width between parent and children of list, and vertical centering parent

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am not sure how should I explain but I want to auto width the area(space) between item 1 and 2. I am not sure it is ul or li....

Also I want to verticalize item 1 to the center of its children. I tried so many ways to deal with CSS, but I couldn't fine a solution. Please help and advice.

Now is like

```
-----                                                     -------
| P |              I want to be like this  ->             |  C  |
-----                                                     -------
     -----                                     -------    -------
     | C |                                     |  P  |    |  C  |
     -----                                     -------    -------
     -----                                                -------
     | C |                                                |  C  |
     -----                                                -------
     -----
     | C |
     -----  
                         the width of P will auto change
```

CSS

```
.div {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;    
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="div">Item 1</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="div">Item 1.1</div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="div">Item 1.2</div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="div">Item 1.3</div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="div">Item 1.4</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="div">Item 2</div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="div">Item 3</div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="div">Item 4</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you want to display the child elements only on clicking, or you want to display them too?

Comment: I want to display them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought the fiddle is just an approximate one. But check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/nQvEW/138/

What I have done is , that I have considered the first li elements to be parent elements of class parent and I have positioned them relative to the main page.

```
.parent {
position:relative;
}
```

Secondly , I have considered the ul inside the parent element, and have positioned it relative  to the parent li ( which comprises of both parent li and the child ul elements ) and have applied the left attribute appropriately.

```
.parent ul{
position:relative;
left:20%;
}
```

Thirdly, I have positioned the div element inside the parent element to be absolute with respect to the parent element. You can tweak a bit, the top percentage. This is actually important since the parent element needs to be shifted down in order to maintain the margins from the child elements.  For ideal case, the top attribute value should be 50% though.

```
.parent .div {
position:absolute;
top:40%;
}
```

​

Comment: Thank you very much! Although I need to take time to understand the code, I believe this is the answer!

Comment: There are several ways to do a problem in CSS. I think its one of them!

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to handle this. in your example, you don't really express an overall width so lets say you want the P and C both together.

```
<div class="containBoth" style="width:500px;">
  <div class="c" style="float:right;width:300px;">
    <ul>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

<div class="p" style="margin-right:20px">
    P 
</div>
</div><!-- close containBoth-->
```

of course, I used inline styles for speed. You should assign classes like I did and put the actual css in a sheet. I just did both here to show you. Remember, that when you float something to the right, it needs to come first in the html document, that is the content/div/etc for easiness.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I separate the parent and children into different div, the visual effect may done. And actually I might not need ul li to do this....However I gonna had a lot of function into them so I want to keep them connect as ul li......any other solutions?